# Storyboard generated UIScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I understand there are many questions relating to this, but i don't seem to be able to successfully apply any of their methods. I'm using xcode version 5.1.1 for iOS 7+. I have a basic app which i want a single page to scroll, but the scroll never scrolls.

my hierarchy looks like this:

```
-> View Controller

 -> View 

  -> Scroll View   

   -> generic content
```

To make the content visible to allow me to edit it easily, i changed the **viewcontroller** to **freeform** via the **attribute inspector** then modified the height in the **size inspector** to 2000.

I've tried having the **scrollView** the same size as the **controllerView** (320, 2000). And i read that it should be less as having it the same size means there is nothing to scroll. I then changed the **scrollView** to the default height(320, 568) meaning the view was bigger than the scroll view.

In either method only the 568 worth of content are displayed and anything beyond isn't accessible.

I've tried adding a **runtime attribute** to the scroll view with a **keypath** of `contentSize` a **type** of `Size` and a **value** of `{320,2000}` which doesn't appear to make any difference.

In the file inspector i've un-ticked the use **autolayout** property, which again doesn't appear to effect my results.

It seems like it should be very simple, if your screensize is bigger than default you should be allowed to scroll, but nothing i have tried seems to work, can anyone shine any light on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried to set contentSize manually in code?

Comment: @NikitaTook no, i assumed it does the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the scrollview contentSize to something bigger than the scrollview frame size

Comment: no difference here, if i have the scrollView set to 2000 and the contentSize of that scrollView set to 568, it only displays up to 568

Comment: sorry - I meant the other way around(editing my answer)- contentSize bigger than frame

Comment: same again when swapped around, does the size of my controllerView matter in this example? its currently 2000, scrollView 568, scrollView contentsize 2000.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. One thought: it sounds like you might have made quite a few changes to the scrollview through your process of testing? Maybe start with a  fresh scrollview in a normal view controller. Leave auto layout off. Then just set one thing in code: the scrollview contentSize to something bigger than the frame (like 2000 as you have). Obviously make sure you have something like a UILabel in the scrollview so you can see it moving. It should all work like that.

Comment: worked first time on a fresh scroll, turns out my content on my page was making the 'scroll' action difficult on my mac

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to setup your UI in scroll view.

Steps. : -

1.) Take UIScrollView in view of UIViewController and goto attribute inspector of UIViewController and make its size freedom.

2.) Now increase length of view under UIViewController and also scrollView under view. Now your scroll height according to UI requirement.

3.) Setup your UI and after that make UIViewController inferred.

4.) Make UIScrollView outlet and set its content size according to requirnment at runtime.
    [self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];

5.) Make Use Auto Layout uncheck.

6.) Enjoy coding... (Y)